# Ionic 3 HTTP Post Request Trouble

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am having trouble getting my post request to work in Ionic.  I am able to get "page loaded" to print to the console, and since I am sure the username and password are provided in JSON format are in my database, it should print "response received" or error out but neither are happening.  I am expecting "response received" since the user is for sure in the database. I feel like I'm close on the format but might be missing something.  I'm new to Ionic so go easy, and thanks so much.

login.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TabsPage } from '../tabs/tabs';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Http, Response, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http) {

    let loginData = {
      "username": "test@test.com",
      "password": "password"
    };

    let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    
    // var headers = new Headers();
    // headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
    // const requestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    console.log('page loaded');
    return this.http.post('https://pupper.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/login', loginData, httpHeaders)
      .subscribe(data => {
        // console.log(data['_body']);
        console.log('response received');
       }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad Login Page');
  }

  login() {
    this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage);
  }
    
 }
```

Comment: Which platform are you using, browser, ios or android? Also, do you see any errors on the console?

Comment: I am testing it in the browser by seeing an iOS and android view with 'ionic serve --lab' and I'm not seeing any errors on the console which is the weird thing.